# how to give equal width span using flex model?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

can you please tell me how to give equal width span using flex model ?

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <ul class="">
    <li class="results_table_li flex_one">
      <span >1</span><span>2</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>55</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span >8</span><span>0</span><span>8</span><span>44</span><span>56</span>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
  body{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    ul {
      list-style:none
    }

    .results_table_ul {
      display: flex;
    }

    .results_table_li {
      display: flex;

    }

    .flex_one {
      flex: 1;
    }
```

`124555`  will get equal `width` can you please tell me how I will give `equal` width to all  `span` element which is the child of `li`.I am using `display:flex` .I also try `flex:1`

code link
https://jsbin.com/huzeqedola/edit?html,css,output

Comment: li {display: flex} span {flex: 1}

Comment: @VXp, that will not give them equal width in any circumstance. If one of them has more content it will have bigger width. The short answer, naveen is: it's complicated. Depending on case, you might want to use `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` on children or `justify-content` on parent. It also depends on what you mean by "equal width".

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Of course but I don't see the content is the case, yet. Then simple `word-break: break-all` will do the trick.

Comment: @VXp, I worry about people answering for the above case while answers (and questions) on SO should be more generic in order to be helpful to future visitors. That's why the first problem is the question is not clear enough, IMHO.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Agreed.

Comment: @sorry guys I will give you more clarity .I need equal columns using `ul`,`li` ,'span'

Comment: in span there is only `2` to `3` numberic dgit

Comment: you want equal with considering the biggest width ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this?

`.results_table_li span{ 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
      <ul>
        <li class="results_table_li flex_one">
          <span >1</span>
          <span>2</span>
          <span>4</span>
          <span>5</span>
          <span>55</span>
        </li>
        <li class="results_table_li flex_one">
            <span >8</span>
            <span>0</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>44</span>
            <span>56</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Css

```
 ul {
  list-style:none
}

.results_table_ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.results_table_li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex_one {
  flex: 1;
}
ul li span {
  display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this will answer your question.  It sounds like you need an equal width `<span>` regardless of the content in each one.

One solution would be to add a `min-width:{}` value to the spans.

Of course, once the content inside each span goes beyond the declared minimum width they will no longer be even, but maybe for your purposes this can work?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.results_table_li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="results_table_li">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5456</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>55</span>
    </li>
    <li class="results_table_li">
      <span>8</span>
      <span>5456</span>
      <span>0</span>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>44</span>
      <span>56</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```